# How to create new xcode target automatically for existing project

Tags: python, ios, ruby, automation, target

In need a script or a tool to create a new xcode target, assets folder and info.plist for that target. for existing xcode project without needing to do that manually via xcode

Answer (score 0):

I have a project and i need to do the same in order to use it to CI. I need to do it without Xcode.